# ExecJS - Javascript object instances in Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby, execjs

If I have a javascript object, I would normally interact with the object and its methods like this:

```
var obj = someObject.getInstance();
var result = obj.someMethod();
```

where someMethod is defined like this:

```
someObject.prototype.someOtherMethod = function() { //do stuff };
someObject.prototype.someMethod = function(foo) { this.someOtherMethod(); };
```

However, I am getting an error when I want to call someMethod in Ruby via ExecJS:

```
context = ExecJS.compile(# the javascript file)
context.call('someObject.getInstance().someMethod') 
# Gives a TypeError where Object has no method 'someOtherMethod'
```

On the other hand, functions that are defined in the javascript module are working fine:

```
someFunction = function() { // do stuff };

# in Ruby
context.call('someFunction') # does stuff
```

Can ExecJS handle Javascript objects and their methods, or am I only able to call functions with it?

With regards to the specific application, I am looking into https://github.com/joenoon/libphonenumber-execjs, but the parse function in Libphonenumber does not work for the above reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discovered the answer through some experimentation.  I managed to get the desired functionality by using context.exec() instead of call.

```
js = <<JS
var jsObj = someObject.getInstance();
var res = jsObj.someMethod();
return res;
JS

context.exec(js);
```

However, if your method returns a Javascript object, you have to serialize it first or otherwise parse the results so that it can be returned by ExecJS into a suitable Ruby object.